# Interferences while using two ToF cameras

Tags: point-cloud-library, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, 3dcamera

Im using a DS325 from SoftKinetic and a Creative Senz3D at the same time with the DepthSense-SDK and the Point-Cloud-Library (on Ubuntu 15.04). But I got strong interferences.

Is there a possibility to control the laser (software side) either to send the light in a special frequency or to turn it off and on alternating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
SoftKinetic is sharing a beta driver on request. With this driver you can set the IlluminationLevel (1-100).

Setting it to 1-49 turns the laser OFF
Setting it to 50-100 turns the laser ON

This works for the DS325 for older models (like DS311) the behaviour is a bit different.

Comment: Great that you answered your own question, however probably this thread would me more suitable for [superuser](http://superuser.com/). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57999/225842.